# PHP Crops Image not as expected

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to crop an image using `jcrop` and a `form`. When I submit the form all the required data to crop the image, aswell as the image itself, `POSTS` correctly.

Then I'll upload the original image to the server, and store the filename along with some other data in the database.

After that I start cropping, which does something. But not what I would expect.

I'm trying to crop the following image: [image]

As you can see I´m trying to only crop the head off.

When I save the image I´ll get the following as result:

[image]

Which as I said is not what I expected.

This is my saving and cropping function:

```
function file_upload($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $w, $h){
            //Bestand opslaan op de server
            $filename = str_replace(' ', '', $_FILES['schilderij_toevoegen_file']['name']);
            $target  = '../Storage/portfolio/'.$filename;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['schilderij_toevoegen_file']['tmp_name'], $target);

            //Betand hercroppen
            $copy = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
            $new = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
            $size = getimagesize($target);
            imagecopyresampled($new, $copy, 0, 0, $x2, $y2, $w, $h, $size[0] * 0.5, $size[1] * 0.5);
            imagejpeg($new, '../Storage/portfolio/crp_'.$filename);

            print 'X1: '.$x1.', Y1: '.$y1.', X2: '.$x2.', Y2: '.$y2.', Width: '.$w.', Height: '.$h;

        }
```

I'm very new with this cropping function PHP has, so I would appreciate any kind of help.

Edit: These values where used in the function above: `X1: 0, Y1: 115, X2: 181, Y2: 299, Width: 181, Height: 184` The original image size is `425x348`

Comment: have you tried changing the coordinates?

Comment: Then keep changing the coordinates until you get what you want, and with luck you will have learnt how the cropping works

Comment: I've switched the `x1's` and `x2's` and so forth. Used `$w` and `$h` instead of the `$size[0]` and `$size[1]`.

Comment: Wow, `imagecopyresampled($new, $copy, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $w, $h, $w, $h);` fixed it. Thanks for the help :)